# Spring STS(spring tool suite) showing ransomeware, what should i do?

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

I was working on spring project using spring STS this is my first time using it, it was running fine from last 15 days but today when i was in middle of my work malwarebytes shown this error and removed sts.exe from my computer, any help very much appreciated. [removal message shown below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tskut.png) and [malware bytes version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShFtF.png)

[image: malwarebytes message]

Comment: From where did you download STS?

Comment: Official website, this link http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.9.2.RELEASE/dist/e4.7/spring-tool-suite-3.9.2.RELEASE-e4.7.2-win32-x86_64.zip zip file 64bit

Comment: I've downloaded this file and compute a sha256 checksum of `5b08887c0cc9e990e33a58e64a956b168555544ac1789a3b2c3170a6c8b9a3ec`. Do you have the same value for your file?

Comment: [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com) cannot be used because the file is bigger than 256Mb...

Comment: yes, same hash 5b08887c0cc9e990e33a58e64a956b168555544ac1789a3b2c3170a6c8b9a3ec   check [img link](https://imgur.com/uSp8Yvq)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a false positive. As you have a premium subscription to Malewarebytes, you should report the suspicious file via this procedure:

[Submit a malicious file or website to Malwarebytes](https://support.malwarebytes.com/docs/DOC-1087)

If it's a false positive, they will improve their detection rules and if it's a real ransomeware they will alert the provider of STS (Pivotal).